# How to delete all the duplicate rows of a column based on if even just one of the duplicates has a certain value in another column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, duplicates

I  have a data frame in R where one column is a numeric factor for ID number with multiple encounters of the same ID , and one column is age and the last column is status which consists of 10 levels. I am trying to remove all duplicate ID rows if just one of the duplicate ID's has a certain value at anytime in status column.

Here is my code I am trying to remove all duplicate ID's if any of them has the listed status level

```
D1 = DD %>%
    group by(ID, status)%>%
    filter(!duplicated(ID) & if(any(status = c('11','13','14','19','20'))))
    example data actual data is has over 100000 rows
```

Here is a sample data set. The only duplicate that should not be removed is ID-987
Id.data<-data.frame(
ID = c(564,758,987,1568,4987,413578,987,65647,4895,564,135,1568),
gender= c("male","female","female","male","male","female","female","male", "female","male","male","male"),
status = c(11,8,6,13,14,8,12,8,10,19,16,10),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

Comment: Can you please include a sample of `DD` in your question by using `dput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, may be this works

```
library(dplyr) 
DD %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(!(n() > 1 & any(status %in% c('11', '13', '14', '19', '20')))) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     ID status
#  <int> <chr> 
#1     3 9     
#2     4 6     
#3     4 5     
#4     5 20
```

#### data

```
DD <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), status = c("9", 
"11", "10", "13", "10", "9", "6", "5", "20")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: worked great thank you. I have been trying for a while to it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to add a sample data frame. Here is my proposed solution:

```
library(dplyr)
DD <- data.frame(ID = factor(sample(123490:123499, 100, replace = TRUE)),
                 status = sample(11:20, 100, replace = TRUE))


filter(DD, !duplicated(ID) & status %in% c(11, 13, 14, 19, 20))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: An example would  be like DD<- data.frame( ID= factor( c =(123, 1675, 456, 123 ,76, 469, 1675, 123, 92356, 76, 123)), status = factor ( c= ( 4, 10, 8, 13, 1, 14  20, 19, 20, 4, 10)))  And it would only return ID values of (456,76,469,92356,76)

Comment: I am a bit confused now. You have only unique factors in `ID`. ID 456 has a status of 8, which is not in your list.

By the way, if you enclose code in `, then it will look nicer.

Comment: I am sorry for that. It's my first post I will do so in the future thank you for the feed back.

Comment: No worries, I hope the comments are useful. Welcome to R!